# Check whether an .iso file exactly matches a CD or DVD

Tags: windows, optical-media

I am looking for a program that can check whether an .iso file exactly matches a CD or DVD.

The program should run on Microsoft Windows. Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a hash of the iso, and a hash of the cd - either by converting it to an iso, or by referencing it directly (don't know if windows can do this, linux and mac can).

As a bonus, if you are downloading ISO images from a legit source there will often be lists of the hashsums for various algorithms that are signed with a public/private keypair, so you can compare what you download with what they say you should have gotten.

QuickHash is Free and free and cross platform - http://quickhash-gui.org/

Answer (score 1):

ImgBurn (a free disk copying and burning application) has exactly what you want to do.

Here's from their site:

> **Verify** - Check a disc is 100% readable. Optionally, you can also have
>   ImgBurn compare it against a given image file to ensure the actual
>   data is correct

You can download it here http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/imgburn.html

[image]

[image]